# Efficient way to detect file change/deletion python

Tags: python, cron

I will have a file running in the background on my computer, and I need it to run a task when a *specific* file is changed or deleted. I know that I could do this by continuously reading the file, but this seems to me to be inefficient. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: You used the tag `cron` which is I think a good idea. Did you went into that direction ?

Comment: @Roy2012 the solution should work on all Linux based distributions.

Comment: @pyOliv That could work, how would I do that? (You can just post as answer)

Comment: I would build a script to monitore changes in the file. This script can be written in the langage of your choice. Then, i would call this script using ‘cron’ at the frequency of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that on Linux is to use auditd: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Audit_framework

It's unrelated to python - but it will allow you to 'know' whenever a specific file is modified.